# Possible ways to create a turn based system using PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Right, I'm trying to create a system where by the user can do something, but then must wait until all the other users in the mysql table have made their move, i.e

User1 makes move, user2 and 3 must wait
user2 makes move, user 1 and 3 must wait
user3 makes move, user 1 and 2 must wait
user1 makes move...

One way I thought of was to give each of the users an number (ranging from 1 to the total number of players, say 6) and then when a player makes a move, set their number to the max number (6) and decrease everyone else's number by one, so the one with the minimum number is the only one who can play.

That's my only idea, is there an easier or alternative way?

Comment: I think programmers.stackexchange.com is a better place for this question.

Comment: Agreed with Toby; from stackoverflow.[meta](http://bit.ly/zrmGDQ):

"Stack Overflow questions almost all have actual source code in the questions or answers. It’s much rarer (though certainly OK) for a Programmers question to contain source code."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be just store the last move date as a datetime.  When you need to check if a user can move, simply just select out of the table all of the other players where the last move date is less than or equal to the current player's last move date.  If the number of rows is not 0, then the player cannot move yet.

The benefits of this approach is the simplicity- every time you allow a player to make a move, just update the column with the current date and time.

Answer (score 1):

**Your proposed solution seems a little circuitous:**

- You're updating+reading every player every move, when the minimum information you need to maintain is *whose move it is*.
- You're losing information about player order as you encode next turn information.

**A high-level solution:**

1. Create a `games` table, one row per game, with a column like `INT currentTurn`
2. Create a `gameUsers` table on a per-game basis, linked to its game in `games`
3. *Do* assign each of the *n* users in `gameUsers` an `INT playerOrder` ranging *[1-n]*
4. Only accept a move from `playerN` if `playerN == "SELECT playerID FROM gameUsers WHERE playerOrder = currentTurn"`
5. After a successful move: `"UPDATE games SET currentTurn = currentTurn + 1 WHERE game = thisGame"`

I believe above table structure is a good object oriented representation of an actual game model. You can stash other per-game things into `games` like winner, length, date, etc. Pardon the pseudoSQL.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a table with column `hasMoved tinyint(1) required default 0`, and query for `where hasMoved == 0`; if the query returns null, then all players have moved.

(Note: this is based on "must wait for all other users", NOT for a strict move order - i.e. 'A' must move before 'B' must move before 'C', etc.)

Additionally, queries using this method is somewhat slow and (to me) seems somewhat unnecessarily resource-intensive - perhaps think about using Ajax instead?

Answer (score 0):

Have a game sequence number that starts at zero. Have a "last moved" number for each player. When a player moves, set their "last moved" number equal to the game sequence number. Once every player has moved, increment the game sequence number.

You may want to use a timeout though, otherwise a player who doesn't move can delay the other players indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

I would first determine $sequence by calculating speed. Then comparing speeds to determine order. Then use the order to send out notices for their move. Use a timestamp to ensure the user doesn't take over a day or however long, you will need a cron job just for this.

Have a variable or array hold the first n last sequence so u can easily move the last moved player to the back without mixing uP orders.

Have the page check the players order sequence and not allow action unless it's at 1 or 0. Be sure to sanitize inputs so no manipulation exists. Then insert your form and graphics and game equations.

Answer (score 0):

You can save date-time of the last move of the each user. So when you DESC sort this table by this date-time column, you will have to fetch only the first row of the result, that will contain the ID of the allowed to make move player.